# Anime series with live-action segments, time travel, dinosaurs and spaceships

Tags: story-identification, time-travel, anime, space, dinosaurs

I am looking for a series. I saw it somewhere online in recent years, but from the style I would guess it was made in the 90s.

I saw it in Japanese language, without subtitles, so my understanding of the plot is limited.

Protagonists are a boy and a girl, maybe 10 to 12 years old.

It had live-action segments, taking place in a kind of spaceship or station, with both protagonists and some kind of animated flying robot or alien. These segments mostly consisted of talking without much else going on.

The other segments are anime, with one or both of the characters going on time travel to the time of dinosaurs. Later episodes also take place in space.

What I remember of the plot:

- The protagonist girl befriends a young sauropod, which is killed by carnivorous dinosaurs.
- The protagonist later encounter intelligent anthropomorphic dinosaurs. There are two races, "raptors" with dark skin and a kind of biped dinosaurs with tail-clubs and white or bright-pink skin whose name I did not catch.
- Later episodes take place on spaceships of the anthropomorphic dinosaurs.
- The raptors are viewed as antagonists for the most part, but at the end it seems that the queen of the other dinosaur race is revealed as the villain, and the raptor leader becomes an ally.
- I think there was a caveman with them on a ship, who sacrificed himself to allow the others to escape when a ship is evacuated.

What it is not:

- *Daikyouryuu Jidai*
- *Kyouryuu Boukenki Jura Tripper*
- *Uninhabited Planet Survive* / *Mujin Wakusei Survive*

I think the title was something generic like "prehistoric planet" or similar. I remember thinking that it would be really hard to find it again if you do not know exactly what it was called. It seems I was right, because I can no longer find it.

Comment: Were there any transforming vehicles?

Comment: @Shawn No transforming vehicles

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found it. It is *[Kyoryu Wakusei](https://animanga.fandom.com/wiki/Dinosaur_Planet)* / 恐竜惑星 (*Dinosaur Planet*), made in 1993/94.

Description from the [Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/kyouryuuwakusei):

> Some segment from an educational variety show called "Tensai TV-kun" (天才てれびくん).
>
> First show in the Virtual Trilogy, a mix of anime and live action shots. The story is about the TV Warriors who enter a virtual simulation of the past and encounter Dinosaur-humanity.

Comment: Glad you found it. Please don't forget to mark your answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer), although, as this is a self-answer, you'll need to wait until the question is 48 hours old before the site will let you do that.